# `arm-none-eabi-g++ -print-sysroot` is empty

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, arm-none-eabi-gcc

If I unpacking the toolchain via [gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-rm/10.3-2021.07/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.07-x86_64-linux.tar.bz2) and run

```
$ arm-none-eabi-g++ --help
...
-print-sysroot           Display the target libraries directory.
...
$ arm-none-eabi-g++ -print-sysroot
$ /opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.07/bin/../arm-none-eabi
```

I get the sysroot path, but if I use the package manager

```
$ # ubuntu 20.04
$ sudo apt install gcc-arm-none-eabi libnewlib-arm-none-eabi \
                   libnewlib-dev libstdc++-arm-none-eabi-newlib 

$ arm-none-eabi-g++ --help
...
-print-sysroot           Display the target libraries directory.
...
$ arm-none-eabi-g++ -print-sysroot
$ # I would expect /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi, but it's empty
```

the sysroot path is empty.

Is this always the case for `apt install`? Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I have the same issue, except with latest from here:
https://developer.arm.com/Tools%20and%20Software/GNU%20Toolchain